# TAS vs TTAS locking

Tags: performance, x86, locking, atomic, spinlock

I'm comparing TAS vs TTAS locking.
Here is the code:

TAS:

```
.globl _tas_lock_acquire
_tas_lock_acquire:
    repeat:
        lock btsw $0, (%rdi)
    jc repeat
    ret

.globl _tas_lock_release
_tas_lock_release:
    lock btrw $0, (%rdi)
    ret
```

TTAS:

```
.globl _ttas_lock_acquire
_ttas_lock_acquire:
    try_lock:
        lock btsw $0, (%rdi)
        jc spinwait
        ret
    spinwait:
        btsw $0, (%rdi)
        jc spinwait
        jmp try_lock

.globl _ttas_lock_release
_ttas_lock_release:
    btrw $0, (%rdi)
    ret
```

If performance of TAS locking is similar to c++11 atomic_flag (no difference), then TTAS is significantly slower (order of 3 magnitude).
I'm testing on "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU         540  @ 3.07GHz".

What is my mistake that results in the slowness?

Comment: The question of comparing arises from "The art of multiprocessor programming", chapter 7, comparing of TAS vs TTAS.

Comment: Unlock should be just a pure store.  You do own the lock at that point so it's not a bug to do a non-atomic RMW on the whole 16-bit word containing the lock, but it's slower for no benefit.  (And `lock btr` is even slower).  If other threads could be doing anything with the other bits in that word, `btr` without `lock` could step on them.  (Or actually the 32-bit dword that contains it because you used a bitstring instruction.  16-bit operand-size is normally the worst choice in 64-bit mode.)  Anyway, just use `mov` to unlock.

Comment: Also, put a `pause` inside your spin loops, especially the one that (is supposed to) spin read-only.  And if you aren't using other bits in the low byte for anything else, you don't need bit instructions, just `xchg`, like in [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246263)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my mistake is in _ttas_lock_acquire implementation, spinwait label.
It should be "bt" instruction, not "bts".